# Why are templates loaded when they are in a ng-switch?

Tags: angularjs

In my html I have this piece of code which is part of a table:

```
<tr ng-show="isRowVisible(certificate.Id)" class="no-hover">
    <td colspan="{{ columnChooser.getNumberOfVisibleColumns() }}" data-ng-switch="isRowVisible(certificate.Id)">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <certificate-details-window
                certificate-id="certificate.Id"
                form-data="formData"
                visible="isRowVisible(certificate.Id)"
                close="toggleDetailsRow($event, certificate.Id)"
                on-certificate-saved="certificateSaved(certificate)"
                on-customer-saved="customerSaved(customer)">
            </certificate-details-window>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When thus user clicks the row above, this row becomes visible because the `isRowVisible(..)` function returns true.

When the page is loaded, the `isRowVisible()` function always return false, which means that the `<certificate-details-window>` tag is not rendered. But the template of the directive is loaded form the server....

This tag however, contains also other custom tags. To my surprise I see in the Network tab of Chrome that all of the templates of the custom tags are loaded from the server. How is this possible?

Comment: can you post controller and directive `certificate-details-window>`?

Comment: That's just how ng-switch and ng-if work. If you want to show/hide things, use ng-show.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I thought when using ng-switch, the html is parsed at the moment the condition passes the evaluation...

Comment: @Martijn The moment the condition passes the evaluation, the HTML is requested from the server. However that is an asynch operation, so the rest of you javascript is executing first.

Comment: @MikeRobinson '(...) evaluation, the HTML is requested from the server. ' That is exactly my point. I see that the HTML is requested/loaded from the server even the condition does not pass the evaluation.

Comment: Ah I understand what you're saying now. I wish I could explain better why, but I'm fairly certain if you change that from a function to an attribute you'll have much more predictable behavior.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I'm sorry but what should I change to an attribute?

Comment: @Martijn Educated guess here, but isRowVisible() will work if it's an attribute of a model on the scope.

Comment: How come no one has answered this? Why does directive load its template even though it does not activate upon ng-switch